# Angularjs - dynamic elements/templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to figure out the best way to create dynamic elements.

Basically, i have a multi-select list, eg...

```
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

Once selected either one or more, it needs to generate elements for these selections such as...

```
Item 1
Name: ....
Quantity: ....
```

add insert to the view. Would i need to define all these hidden elements in the view?

Or should i use a directive? If you could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a combo of `ng-repeat` and `ng-show`/`ng-if`.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" style="margin-top:10px">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.selected">Item {{$index + 1}}
    <div style="margin-left:30px" ng-show="item.selected">
        <div>Name: {{item.name}}</div>
        <div>Quantity: {{item.quantity}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/Mvydk1CMG8PM7LTmI57R?p=preview